# Quick Check on Bayes Rule in Terms of Sets

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Recently, I took a quiz with a question asking me to find the conditional probability of X given Y in terms of sets.

I solved the question as:

$$Pr(X|Y) = \frac{Pr(Y|X)Pr(X)}{Pr(Y)}$$
$$Pr(X|Y) = \frac{Pr(X \cap Y)}{Pr(Y)}$$

The answer was revealed to be "the probability of the intersection of X and Y, divided by the probability of X." Have I made a mistake somewhere? Any way I think about it, $Pr(Y)$ should be the denominator.

Comment: Both are correct when denominators $\ne 0$.

Comment: @zkutch would that not imply that Pr(X) had to equal Pr(Y)? I don't understand how both answers would yield the same result.

Comment: Generally $P(X)\ne P(Y)$. To assure in both replace in second formula $X$ and $Y$ and use in first.

Comment: @zkutch I'm not exactly sure what you mean by your last comment. But I just want to confirm that $Pr(X|Y) = \frac{Pr(X \cap Y)}{Pr(Y)} \neq  \frac{Pr(X \cap Y)}{Pr(X)}$ (in the general case where Pr(X) does not necessarily equal Pr(Y)).

Comment: Wrote answer. Ask if/when you find something unclear.

Comment: @Camellia99 you are correct, it should be "the probability of the intersection of X and Y, divided by the probability of Y".

Answer (score -1):

Let's take definition of [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability)  of X given Y, when $P(Y) \gt 0$
$$P(X|Y)=\frac{P(X \cap Y)}{P(Y)}\quad (1)$$
Obviously, when $P(X) \gt 0$ we have
$$P(Y|X)=\frac{P(Y \cap X)}{P(X)}\quad (2)$$
Now solving $P(Y \cap X)$ from second $P(Y \cap X) =P(Y|X) \cdot P(X)$ and putting it in (1), using $Y \cap X = X \cap Y$, gives
$$P(X|Y)=\frac{P(X \cap Y)}{P(Y)}=\frac{P(Y|X) \cdot P(X)}{P(Y)}\quad (3)$$

As to the your last question in comments, then generally, when $P(X) \ne P(Y)$ and $P(X \cap Y) \ne 0$, then of course $P(X|Y) \ne P(Y|X)$.

Comment: The question is about $P(X|Y)$. Why should $P(Y|X)$ be relevant?

Comment: @user159517. Question contain $P(Y|X)$,  it is (2) in my answer, in its first line and is asking about connections between 2 formulas, which is in my answer (1), (3).  So, **everything is correct and in place**. Are you asking about connection between (2) and (1), (3) or what you mean under "relevant"?

Comment: the OP wanted to know whether their argument in deriving the formula for $P(X|Y)$ was correct, a question you do not answer explicitly (although it is what line (1) says).  The formula for $P(Y|X)$ has nothing to do with this question and is not useful in my opinion.

Comment: @user159517.  Very first answer is in my 1st comment and then in answer. There is no deriving/elaborating formula for $P(X|Y)$, in OP but only 2 results. My answer explicitly connects these 2 to definition of conditional probability and proofs it. Without conception of $P(Y|X)$ it is impossible to get answer for $P(X|Y)$ as it is in OP first formula. If you have something more, then only "opinion", then for everybody will be useful if you elaborate it explicitly.

Comment: In your comment you say that "both are correct", but the answer given by the quiz "the probability of the intersection of X and Y, divided by the probability of X" is not equal to $P(X|Y)$, while the OP's answer is correct.

Comment: @user159517. Both formulas given of course  are correct and the connection with $P(Y|X)$ is obvious and undeniable, but now you started talking about something completely different, i.e. about the sentence in quotes. The latter is answered by my equation (2) and thus everything is in order again.